# How to Remove Space Between Items in LazyVerticalGrid in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How to remove space between items in LazyVerticalGrid in Jetpack Compose? I want to remove space between items.

```
val list = mutableListOf("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit")

@Composable
fun MyUi() {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        content = {
            items(list.size) { index ->
                Text(
                    text = list[index],
                )
            }
        })
}
```

what I have,

```
lorem                 ipsum
dolor                 sit
```

what I want,

```
lorem ipsum
dolor sit
```

Comment: Does each cell/item have fixed height and width?

Comment: @Abhimanyu No doesn't have.

Comment: In that case, you can use a `LazyColumn` with a `Row` of multiple items to create the grid you require.

Comment: @Abhimanyu I tried using lazycolumn with a row but didn't know how. Please, can you share some code?

Comment: I have added an answer for reference using LazyColumn. It has some assumptions as it is not clear what is the expectation when a column has long text. Is there a max width for each column? If the answer is not fitting for your use case add comments with the conditions and I will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible bcoz you are set **GridCells.Fixed(2)** the size. that's why this split into two parts. also, there is one way but it's not the same as you ask. you can use **GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = 20.dp)** instead of **GridCells.Fixed(2)**.

Comment: They could at least make it possible to center items

Comment: @user128440 yes you can use one box and arrangement maybe it's work!

Answer (score 1):

This does answer the original question asked.
I am sharing this here as the OP had asked this in the comments.

```
// Note: In the screenshots provided the text used is large
// I am truncating it here as it is not relevant
val words = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.".split(" ")

@Composable
fun LazyGridUsingLazyColumnDemo(
    items: List<String> = words,
    columns: Int = 2,
) {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp
    val textMeasurer: TextMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()

    val rows = ceil(items.size.toDouble() / columns).toInt()
    var nthColumnWidth = MutableList(columns) { col ->
        items.filterIndexed { index, _ ->
            index % columns == col
        }.maxOf {
            with(density) {
                textMeasurer.measure(it).size.width.toDp()
            }
        }
    }

    // This is a fallback to act similar to a grid view when there is not enough space for all the columns to be as large as required
    var calculatedColWidthSum = 0.dp
    nthColumnWidth.forEach {
        calculatedColWidthSum += it
    }
    if (calculatedColWidthSum > screenWidth) {
        nthColumnWidth = MutableList(columns) {
            screenWidth / columns
        }
    }

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .statusBarsPadding()
            .navigationBarsPadding(),
    ) {
        items(rows) { row ->
            Row {
                repeat(columns) { col ->
                    val index = row * columns + col
                    if (index < items.size) {
                        Text(
                            text = items[index],
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .then(
                                    if (col < nthColumnWidth.size) {
                                        Modifier
                                            .width(
                                                width = nthColumnWidth[col],
                                            )
                                    } else {
                                        Modifier
                                    }
                                ),
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the amount of spacing you want between the items, by doing:

```kotlin
LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp), // this sets the padding between the items verically
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp) // and this sets the padding between the items horizontally
)
```